# How to test if PHP mail() has successfully delivered mail

Tags: php

How can I test if `mail()` has successfully delivered mail?

Comment: there is no choice in inbulid php function to know whether receiver received mail or not, even we can not detect is it valid mail id or not

Answer (score 21):

Well `mail()` simply returns a boolean value depending on whether the mail was successfully accepted for delivery. From the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) site:

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

So you can test to see if it's been "sent", however checking if it's been delivered is another story.

Comment: mail() returns true doesn't mean the email is delivered successfully. u may get back a "mail delivery failure" message from the server which receives the email (eg. no such user name) after a few minutes

Comment: I think that's what I said?!

Comment: Ben can you please text something about actual mail delivery check?

Answer (score 16):

As per Ben reply you can check successfully email delivery as below

```
$result = mail('abc@test.com', 'Test Subject', $message);
if(!$result) {   
     echo "Error";   
} else {
    echo "Success";
}
```

For better result you can use PHPMailer. Click on below link for detailed documentation of PHPMailer.

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if(@mail($emailRecipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
  echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
}else{
  echo "Mail Not Sent";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

from the docs:

> "Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery,
>   FALSE otherwise.

It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination. "

Answer (score 2):

From http://php.net/mail

```
Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.
```

Answer (score 0):

The mail() function alone just notifies you that the "email" you have set up is legit and will be send my your email server.

You must check separately for the email address to be legit. A good article can be found [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585)

If these two methods do not work for you well, you can use some "spam" approach using images and your server's log files.

Answer (score -4):

if (isset($_POST["btn_emp"])) {

```
//$hid_emp = ($_POST['hid_emp']);
$employee_name = ($_POST['employee_name']);
$department_id = ($_POST['department_id']);
$serial_number = ($_POST['serial_number']);
$employee_address = ($_POST['employee_address']);
$employee_contact = ($_POST['employee_contact']);
$employee_email = ($_POST['employee_email']);





$insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_employee(department_id,serial_number,employee_name,employee_address,employee_contact,employee_email)VALUES('$department_id', '$serial_number', '$employee_name','$employee_address' ,'$employee_contact', '$employee_email')";
//echo $insert;
//die();
if ($conn->query($insert) === TRUE) {
    //CODE FOR SEND MAIL
    $Mail_Admin_Message = '';
            $Mail_Admin_Message .= '
                <table width="700px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                    <tr height="15px"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
                            Date</b> :<b> '. $serial_number .'</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="15px"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
                            Hi</b> <b> '. $employee_name .'</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="15px"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
                          Your Gift Voucher Code is</b> :<b> '. $department_id .'</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="15px"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
                            Gift Amount</b> :<b> '. $employee_address .'</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="15px"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
                    <tr height="15px"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;">Thanks, <br />DairyKart Team</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>';

            $Mail_To_Admin_ID   = $employee_email;
            $Mail_Admin_Subject = "Employee Details";
            $Mail_Admin_Header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
            $Mail_Admin_Header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
            $Mail_Admin_Header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
            $Mail_Admin_Header .= "X-Priority: 1\n";
            $Mail_Admin_Header .= "From: Employee-Department Project\r\n";
            $Mail_Admin_Header .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
            mail($Mail_To_Admin_ID, $Mail_Admin_Subject, $Mail_Admin_Message, $Mail_Admin_Header);
            //echo $serial_number;
            //echo $employee_email;
            //die();
    echo "<script>alert('Successfully Added & Check Your Mail to know your Details.!!!'); window.location='add-employee.php'</script>";
```

Comment: why it is not sending the email

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -14):

You can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in PHP to receive the user's remote IP address.

Use like so:

```
<?php 

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    echo "User's IP address is: ".$ip;

 ?>
```

Comment: That's not the answer, not even the right question.