# Password recovery not sending email

Tags: php, email, passwords

Password recovery not sending email. But it always say that email was sent. Please help me.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='" . $email . "' ") or die(mysql_error());
    $run = mysql_affected_rows();
    $password = substr(hash('sha512', uniqid(rand(), 1)), 3, 10);
    $pass = hash('sha512', $password);
    if ($run != 0) {
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $to = "$email";
        $subject = "Obnovení hesla";
        $body = "Dobrý den $res->username, vaše nové heslo je $password";
        $additionalheader = "From: <admin@chat-web.com>";
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $additionalheader);
        if ($email) {

            echo"<script>alert('Email byl ĂşspÄ›ĹˇnÄ› odeslĂˇn.')</script>";

        } else {

            echo"<script>alert('EmailovĂˇ adresa $email neexistuje.')</script>";
        }
    }
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='$pass' WHERE email = '$email'")or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide the markup for your form?

Comment: This is my form: http://pastebin.com/hjY7UBAK

Comment: `$run` is going to return false as you're doing a select. You probably want to be using [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows). Also, you should really stop using mysql_* functions and you're currently vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong function to check whether there were any returned rows.

[mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows) returns the number of rows affected by an `INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE`.

[mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows) will return the number of rows returned by a query, which is what you're actually wanting to check.

Comment: Thank you! I replaced mysql_affected_rows() with mysql_num_rows() and it's working now!

Answer (score 1):

For checking response properly try below code:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $additionalheader)) {
    echo "mail sent";
}
else {
    echo "mail not sent";
}
```

You can also print response of $res to know the exact error.
Also, read following post. [How to test if PHP mail() has successfully delivered mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581896/how-to-test-if-php-mail-has-successfully-delivered-mail)

Answer (score 0):

Is mail function working on your server?

Also check your spam folder.

As Jon Stirling said, replace

$run = mysql_affected_rows();

wtih

$run = mysql_num_rows($query);

Comment: Yes mail function is working on my server. And I don't have anything in spam.

Comment: some times mail server sends email after some time. You can check with older code if you made change in code.